# JpaRepository interface implementation, I want to understand where are its methods implemented?

Tags: java, spring

I was following a tutorial when building a project in Spring and the **@Repository interfaces** were extending an other interface **JpaRepository** which added functionalities to the sub interface:

```
@Repository("myRepository")
public interface myRepository extends JpaRepository<Name, Long> {

}
```

In @Service class

```
@Autowired
private MyRepository myrepo;

@Transactional
public Stuff save(Stuff stuff) {
    return myrepo.save(stuff);
}
```

I want to find the actual code for the 'SAVE' method. 
Have downloaded `spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar` and decompiled but could not find the implementation there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spring framework code is hosted on GitHub.
What you are looking for is in this Repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa

One implementation is the SimpleJpaRepository:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java

Comment: This reply is now obsolete.